# How to estimate the limit $\lim_{x\to+\infty}\frac{\int_0^x|\sin(s)|ds}{x}?$

Tags: calculus, integration, limits

I have come across the problem of estimation of the limit $$\lim_{x\to+\infty}\frac{\int_0^x|\sin(s)|ds}{x}.$$
Since it is easy to check that the method of l'Hopital's Rule is incapable of it. I have tried the following:  Since for every $x>\pi,$ there exist unique $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $\theta\in[0, \pi),$ such that $$x=n\pi+\theta,$$
and $$x\to+\infty \Longleftrightarrow n\to\infty.$$
On account of the periodicity of the mapping $s\to |\sin(s)|,$ 
\begin{gather*}
\begin{aligned}
&\lim_{x\to+\infty}\frac{\int_0^x|\sin(s)|ds}{x}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\int_0^{n\pi+\theta}|\sin(s)|ds}{n\pi+\theta}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\int_0^{n\pi}|\sin(s)|ds+\int_{n\pi}^{n\pi+\theta}|\sin(s)|ds}{n\pi+\theta}\\
=&\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2n+\int_0^{\theta}|\sin(s)|ds}{n\pi+\theta}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2+\frac{1}{n}\cdot\int_0^{\theta}|\sin(s)|ds}{\pi+\frac{1}{n}\cdot\theta}\\
=&\frac{2}{\pi}.
\end{aligned}
\end{gather*}

I am not very sure that my trial is sound. Can anyone help me to check my method, or find another  way to estimate this limit?

Comment: Very nicely done, and excellently presented.

Comment: Thanks, Stephen Montgomery-Smith! Your comment gives me confidence.

Comment: Having a dangling free $\theta$ in your limit doesn't make sense. One way to fix it is define $n$ and $\theta$ as a short hand of $\lfloor\frac{x}{\pi}\rfloor$ and $x - n\pi$ and then take the limit in $x$ instead of $n$.

Comment: Since $\theta$ is always in $[0,\pi)$, and $\frac{1}{n}\to 0, $ as $n\to\infty,$ we have $\frac{1}{n}\cdot \theta\to 0,$ as $n\to\infty.$

Comment: I think that $$\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{\int_0^x |sin s|ds}{x}=0$$

Comment: @azhi Yes. But it still makes no sense to write the expression the way you are.

Comment: It seems like it's only a notational problem and achille hui commented on how to fix that. The idea and the answer is still right.

Comment: Actually $\theta=\theta(x,n),$ which as a function of two variables, is bounded. Since $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}=0,$ and $\theta$ is bounded, $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\cdot\theta=0.$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
$\ds{\lim_{x \to \infty}\bracks{{1 \over x}\int_{0}^{x}\verts{\sin\pars{s}}
     \,\dd s}:\ {\large ?}}$.
$$
\int_{0}^{x}\verts{\sin\pars{s}}\,\dd s
=
x\verts{\sin\pars{x}} - \int_{0}^{x}s\sgn\pars{\sin\pars{s}}\cos\pars{s}\,\dd s
=x\verts{\sin\pars{x}} - \int_{0}^{x}\sgn\pars{\sin\pars{s}}\varphi'\pars{s}\,\dd s
$$
where $\ds{\varphi\pars{s} = \int_{0}^{s}t\cos\pars{t}\,\dd t}$.
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{x}\verts{\sin\pars{s}}\,\dd s&=
x\verts{\sin\pars{x}} - \sgn\pars{\sin\pars{x}}\varphi\pars{x}
+
\int_{0}^{x}\varphi\pars{s}\bracks{2\delta\pars{\sin\pars{s}}\cos\pars{s}}\,\dd s
\\[3mm]&=
x\verts{\sin\pars{x}} - \sgn\pars{\sin\pars{x}}\varphi\pars{x}
+
2\int_{0}^{x}\varphi\pars{s}\cos\pars{s}
\sum_{n = -\infty}^{\infty}\delta\pars{s - n\pi}\,\dd s
\\[3mm]&=
x\verts{\sin\pars{x}} - \sgn\pars{\sin\pars{x}}\varphi\pars{x}
+
2\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\pars{-1}^{n}\varphi\pars{n\pi}\Theta\pars{x - n\pi}
\end{align}
However,
$$
\varphi\pars{s} = s\sin\pars{s} - \int_{0}^{s}\sin\pars{t}\,\dd t
 = s\sin\pars{s} + \cos\pars{s} - 1\quad\imp\quad\varphi\pars{n\pi}
= \pars{-1}^{n} - 1
$$
\begin{align}\color{#0000ff}{\large%
\int_{0}^{x}\verts{\sin\pars{s}}\,\dd s
=
2\sin^{2}\pars{x \over 2}\sgn\pars{\sin\pars{x}}
+
4\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\Theta\pars{{x \over \pi} - 2n - 1}}
\end{align}

> \begin{align}\color{#0000ff}{\large%
> \lim_{x \to \infty}\bracks{{1 \over x}\int_{0}^{x}\verts{\sin\pars{s}}\,\dd s}}
> &=
> 4\lim_{x \to \infty}\bracks{{1 \over x}\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}
> \Theta\pars{{x - \pi \over 2\pi} - n}}
> \\[3mm]&=
> 4\lim_{x \to \infty}\bracks{{1 \over 2\pi x + \pi}\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}
> \Theta\pars{x - n}}
> =
> \color{#0000ff}{\large{2 \over \pi}}
> \end{align}